# How to create a custom Twig function class, without using a static method?

Tags: php, twig, templating-engine

I can create a Twig extension for my project like this

```
class Functions extends Twig_Extension{
    public function getName(){return 'foobar';}

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            'loremipsum' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', 'Functions::loremipsum')
        );

    public static function loremipsum($foo) {
        return $foo;
    }
}
```

this works, but I want to use a constructor to inject some data that I need in some functions.

Simply using `'asset'` in `Twig_SimpleFunction` will result in PHP trying to execute the functon `loremipsum()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
        'foo' => new Twig_Function_Method($this, 'bar');
    );
}

public function bar($baz) {
    return $this->foo . $baz;
}
```

Look at all the different classes that `extend Twig_Function` for all the different ways to specify template functions.

For the newer `Twig_SimpleFunction`, it seems you can pass any kind of [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as the second argument to the constructor:

```
new Twig_SimpleFunction('foo', array($this, 'bar'))
```

Comment: sadly, `Twig_Function_Method` (as well as all `Twig_Function_*` classes) is deprecated. It will be removed in 2.0

Answer (score 4):

**Update** from twig version 1.23.1 and up it's as follows:

```
class LogoExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('logo', array($this, 'logo'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function logo()
    {
        return 'result';
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'logo';
    }
}
```

And of course, you add this extension class as a twig extension on `services.yml` config file.

```
services:
    company.twig.extension.logo:
        class:  Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\LogoExtension
        tags:
            -   {   name:   twig.extension}
```