# How to check that element in array are all same in twig?

Tags: php, twig, twig-filter

I have following array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1234"
  1 => "1234"
  2 => "1234"
]
```

In twig I want to check if all element are same return true else return false.

Comment: Do it before passing data to twig. And just send some flag to twig.

Comment: While twig *can* do this natively it would be pretty clunky. If you 100% need to do it inside of a template then you should write your own custom twig function, there are some basics of doing that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662169/how-to-create-a-custom-twig-function-class-without-using-a-static-method